# Can I somehow do an auto swap between staging and production in azure cloud services?

Tags: azure, tfs

I basically want to do a auto swap between staging and production on azure cloud services.

Basically I have a QA environment that needs a fixed IP address for the QA people to test after a developer finishes a task. Because in staging sometimes the ip changes due to some problems that can occur on the TFS builds I want to be able to have a fixed address for the QA team to access without having to click swap manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a VIP SWAP between Production and Staging deployments. The VIPs of both deployments will be EXCHANGED. So Production will become staging and staging will be become Production by IP swap.

If you want your new Staging deployment(previously Production) hold all the latest bits of your application, then you have to re-deploy the application to new staging. This process can be automated through PowerShell. Below resources can be helpful for you to get started with automating deployment process.

[To create a new deployment using PowerShell](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/jumpstart-31-create-and-deploy-new-azure-cloud-service-using-package-cspkg-generated-by-azure-powershell/)

[Run PowerShell script in TFS build process](http://blog.nwcadence.com/whats-new-in-tfs-2013-team-builds-are-able-to-run-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be why the staging deployment/slot is having those problems?

If the need is to programmatically perform the VIP swap, I'd think you could add some custom logic to do so via the Windows Azure service management API.  Add this into your build definition perhaps (e.g. execute via PowerShell).

Comment: Here are some links that might help do what @mcollier is saying: 
REST API call - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460814.aspx 
PowerShell - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152834.aspx